# Restart application with delay in time

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to Restart my application. It is working fine with `Application.Restart();`
But I want to add time delay in this case as it restarting application very rapidly and I want it to take time to restart the application.

```
private void lbllaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Restart();
}
```

Comment: you can use Thread.Sleep(3) or Task.Delay(3). 3 is just sample time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm just assuming that you are using windows forms by the syntax of your example code, `Thread.Sleep('time')` should do the trick for you.
If you want to make the window disappear and then restart itself after the delay you could try and use `Form1.Visible = false` and then the *Sleep* method in your *Application.restart* method, or include those into a helper function like:

```
void restartApplication(Form form1)
{
   form1.Visible = false;
   Thread.Sleep(300);
   Application.restart();
}
```

And then set the form to visible again. This solution isn't very clean tough.

I'd recommend using multithreading. You can set up another thread, that closes your application, pauses and then restarts it. This won't leave your main application in that weird state where it's open but not working.

[An instruction on how to create new Threads can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: nice answer, how ever there was no need for assuming, just look at question tags

Comment: @hessamhedieh True, I missed that ;)

Comment: And i guess by another `thread` u mean another `process`, right?

Comment: @hessamhedieh Well, it is called a `thread` (seee the link in my answer) but basically what it does is create another instance of the program that does it's own stuff (vague description) so you have one thread running your application and one handling the restart. This enables you to have the delay without actually making your application thread unable to do anything, which will look like it crashed for the time of the pause, since only the other Thread in the background stops for the time

Answer (score 3):

You can add `Thread.Sleep` in the method to add a delay

Comment: is it right way to use?? private void lbllaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            Application.Restart();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

Comment: not delay in restart the applciation it stops app to work for some time than restsart I need to close app and took time to start it again

Comment: then you need it in the Program.cs in the main method, before `Application.Run(new Form1());` call

Comment: If you really want to exit the main thread, then wait some time and start the application, you would need some external process to take over control. You could maybe start some script or start another program and then exit your program. There might be some difficulties with starting the other process not as a child process of your Application. But it should be feasible